# How to force a header inclusion from CodeBlocks or from a Makefile?

Tags: c++, header, include, makefile, codeblocks

I have this file:

```
// File.cpp

int main() {
   FuncToChange(4, 6, 9, 12);
}
```

Now, I need to obtain this behaviour:

```
// Config.h

#define FuncToChange($1, $2, $3, $4) NewFunc($1, $3, $4)

// File.cpp

#include "Config.h"

int main() {
   FuncToChange(4, 6, 9, 12);
}
```

How can I do it without modifying the original "File.cpp" file, i.e. without explicitly #include "Config.h"?

**Is it possible to force a header inclusion either from the makefile or from the IDE (CodeBlocks in this case)?**

*Thank you!*

*Platform:*
CodeBlocks 10.05
GCC/MinGW
Windows 7

Comment: Could I know the reason of the down vote? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GCC page on [preprocessor options](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html) page:

```
-include file
    Process file as if #include "file" appeared as the first line of the
    primary source file. However, the first directory searched for file is
    the preprocessor's working directory instead of the directory containing
    the main source file. If not found there, it is searched for in the remainder
    of the #include "..." search chain as normal. If multiple -include options
    are given, the files are included in the order they appear on the command line.
```